# Imagem desaparecendo

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho 3 botões com imagens que posiciono no canto superior direito da tela. Se maximizo a tela para apenas um monitor as imagens aparecem corretamente, mas quando maximizo para dois monitores a primeira imagem vira um traço e a terceira desaparece.

Fiz o teste colocando a segunda imagem para os três botões e aí funciona perfeitamente. Segue abaixo um trecho do código XAML e a configuração das imagens.

Import.png: 512x512, size 81,4 KB.

Chart.png: 128x128, size: 187 KB.

Config.png: 512x512, size 236 KB.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Button 
    x:Name="btnAtualizar" 
    Height="25" 
    Width="25" 
    Grid.Column="3"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Click="btnAtualizar_Click"
    Visibility="Visible"
    >

    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Source="../Images/Import.png"/
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>

<Button 
    x:Name="btnGrafico" 
    Height="25" 
    Width="25" 
    Grid.Column="5"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Click="btnGrafico_Click"
    Visibility="Visible"
    >

    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Source="../Images/Chart.png"/
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>

<Button 
    x:Name="btnGerenciar" 
    Height="25" 
    Width="25"
    Grid.Column="7"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Click="btnGerenciar_Click"
    Visibility="Visible"
    >

    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Source="../Images/Config.png"/
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloquei como resposta que substitui as imagens por outros ícones e assim funcionou, não sei se a resolução das imagens tem algo a ver, pois o problema eram nas duas de 512x512, mas as pessoas abaixo votaram por remover a resposta. Ou seja, preferem que outras pessoas fiquem sem a dica do que eu fiz, além de não ajudarem em nada, com exceção ao rLinhares que ao menos iniciou uma tentativa.

Bacco, Renan, Dvdsamm, Ismael, Sorack, rLinhares

Comment: não entendi...tenta colocar mais informações....tira um print da tela, sei lá

Comment: @RovannLinhalis inseri imagens.

Comment: @Denis Talvez tenhamos nos equivocado não entendendo que aquilo era de fato uma resposta. Como ela foi "removida", não podemos mais visualiza-la. Desculpe.

Comment: Gostaria de saber o pq de agora ter sido marcado como fora de escopo por ramaral e bfavaretto. Por não poder ser reproduzido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está nas imagens, alterei os ícones e está funcionando normalmente agora.